# Display belongsTo category for a product

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I render a `product` table at http://localhost:4200/products which should include the `category` of each product but doesn't.

[image: Screenshot of the application]

The template code:

**app/templates/products/index.hbs**

```
[...]
<tbody>
  {{#each product in model}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{product.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{product.category.name}}
      </td>
[...]
```

*Why doesn't `{{product.category.name}}` display the `product.name`? How can I fix it? Are the mocks wrong?*

### The Application

```
ember new shop
cd shop
ember install:addon ember-cli-scaffold
ember g scaffold product name:string
ember g scaffold category name:string
ember g adapter application
ember g http-mock products
ember g http-mock categories
```

**app/adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  'namespace': 'api'
});
```

**app/models/product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true })
});
```

**app/models/category.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product')
});
```

**server/mocks/products.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var productsRouter = express.Router();

  productsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      'products': [
          {"id":1,"name":"Orange","category":1},
          {"id":2,"name":"Banana","category":1},
          {"id":3,"name":"Potato","category":2}
        ]
      });
  });
  [...]
```

**server/mocks/categories.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var categoriesRouter = express.Router();

  categoriesRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      'categories': [
        {"id":1,"name":"Fruits","products:":[1,2]},
        {"id":2,"name":"Vegetables","products:":[3]}
        ]
      });
  });
  [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `belongsTo` to be async:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true })
});
```

this will do a GET request for every category you access.

Or you can sideload them with products.

Have a look at this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xabonu/1/edit?html,js,output) it shows it can work.

If you look at your mock server you'll see this route:

```
categoriesRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    'categories': {
      id: req.params.id
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see when you request `category` 1 it'll return a object with just that id.

So adding `{ async: true }` does a request per `category` to `/category/1` (when it's category 1 ofcourse). You have to make sure you return the right object.

For example:

```
var categoryList = [
  {"id":1,"name":"Fruits","products:":[1,2]},
  {"id":2,"name":"Vegetables","products:":[3]}
]

categoriesRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    'categories': categoryList.filter(function(c) { 
      return c.id == req.params.id; 
    })[0]
  });
});
```

Comment: I made this change but it didn't help. Is there an other bug in my code?

Comment: I added a jsbin with a working example of a lazily loaded `belongsTo` relation ship. It does work. I'll need a bit more information. Are there any exceptions in the console?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I updated the code and added a screenshot which shows the data. The names for categories are 'undefined'. Do I have to send different JSON?

Comment: Yes that is to be expected. The `name` property will be populated when the promise that gets the category resolves.

Comment: It took me some time to understand the problem (not having a good enough http-mock). Thanks for your effort. BTW: Your categoriesRouter.get doesn't work (I tried cut and paste). I don't know how to fix it otherwise I would have.